# Is there any Api in android for ms office word(.doc/.docx) to (image/html/xml/pdf) conversion

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to make android application which should take **ms word files** i.e.(`.doc/.docx`) files as input and convert it into pdf as final output.
I searched for pdf conversion in android but the output i got was not proper. i tried with `jWordConvert(Qoppa software library)`,it converts word to pdf in java very well but if we try in android it giving error,

`conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1`.

also i tried with `apache poi` library but again it is not showing proper output if my word files contains images or tables..also if we tried with **apache tika** with apache poi, again same results.

**Itext** is also there but its main use is to convert from images/html to pdf, but again output is different from outr expectation..

So my request is, Is there any api which should support android application for word to html/pdf/image conversion with proper output if my word file contains tyables, images etc.
also can i go for JNI, is there any anather way to do it.

please reply. thanx in advance.

Comment: android has limited memory usage, I mean very limited... I wouldn't convert in Android side, but at server side, where I can have much memory as  I want not only 16/24/32mb... but even over 2GB. I did a few string encrypt in Android it took me 5 min in server side it was 3 seconds

Comment: Thanks for reply but my project requirement is that we dont want to do conversion in server side,the conversion should be offline.. if you have any idea about it..thanks

Comment: Good Android devices these days have a whole GB of ram, and even older devices have at least 256-512 MB. I don't see how this is "very limited memory usage"..

Comment: @R.. because your app is limited to 16 or 24 mb ram , no matter how much ram has the Android device

Comment: There definitely should be some way around that, but thanks for clarifying. With highly optimized code that's not using bloated data structures, I think that should be enough for converting word docs anyway, but I doubt any preexisting software exists that can do it in such a space-constrained environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.awk.android.docconv&hl=en) is an app which does what you want to realize.

If there is an app already in app store, for me is very easy to know what that use and how is using...

I hope it helps for you a bit!

Comment: Thanks for reply,the link you suggested converts word to text,i want to convert it into pdf..but anyways its not converting online, thats good for me..there are other apps there in market but all are using internet connection for conversion,they are online conversion apps.you can check "WordtoPdf by ThinkTi.com.Br".. thanks by the way.