# Android: Display large amount of formatted text in an app

Tags: android, text, formatting

I am creating an informative application for school students
I am having all the contents in word file which is formatted.
It contains tables and various styles of fonts,spacing and new lines in it.
Can some one tell me how can i display this content in an android application.
Or is there any way to display the word file as it is.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use open office to read word files on your phone, it's a free application from Google? Do you want code to access MS Word files on Android? There may be an API out there somewhere. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049531/is-there-any-api-in-android-for-ms-office-word-doc-docx-to-image-html-xml-pd What have you tried, have you written any code at all, what issues did you run into? Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854947/android-microsoft-office-library-doc-docx-xls-ppt-etc

Comment: Heyy you can use WebView for this and run your html script in android as your need.

Comment: Actually i had tried converting the word file in to HTML file and then displaying it
i converted the file but I was unable to display it
can you tell me if it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got one solution
I have converted my word file into HTML File online and then displayed it using webview container
thanks all for help

Answer (score 0):

you may upload all your files on server and view directly using webview you need to approach like this

```
WebView urlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.containWebView);
urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
urlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
urlWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
urlWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                + "YOUR_DOC_URL_HERE"); 

public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
  }
```